# how to configure apt-get to use multiple repository components or sections

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, universe

My ubuntu 14.04 installation shows the apt-get uses only one respository section:

```
$ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

While I have commented out the lines with `universe` in the configuration file, and the universe and multiverse are both in the sources.list file:

```
/etc/apt$ grep -r universe *
apt.conf.d/01autoremove:        #"universe/metapackages";
apt.conf.d/01autoremove:        #"universe/oldlibs";
sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
sources.list:deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
sources.list:deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse
sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe main multiverse
```

I'd like to install `libopenal-dev` which is in the `universe` section. But it just can't get to it.

Comment: I must ask, did you update and upgrade after editing sources.list?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually I forgot. Did a "apt-get clean" because that is what you usually do with yum. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding, removing and/or modifying repositories, you must run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```